# Center the body with bigger that screen resolution

Tags: html, css, wordpress, screen-resolution

I attached here the dropbox link of the image drawing of the site..
The current site It starts from the left instead of being centered to the screen..

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7x1uah0j13nljgq/cxc.jpg

and here is my code:
CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0 auto;
font-family: "Source Sans Pro",sans-serif;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
max-width: 1440px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
width: 1000px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set a width for body. Instead, add another wrapper div and set that div's width to 100% with a max-width value of 1440px, like below. You can add an overflow option to body if you end up doing other stuff that might cause the page to exceed the body's boundaries at certain resolutions, but that's not necessary here because the pink container won't ever get wider than the size of its parent () anyway.

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title>
<style>

body {
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

div.outerWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1440px;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro",sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.innerWrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="outerWrapper" style="height: 400px;">
<div class="innerWrapper" style="height: 900%; background-color: red;"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```